# How do I log the contents of the data read from a FileReader in java into an Array List?

Tags: java, arraylist, filereader

to clarify: the code below logs data from the file reader into an array.  In this situation I must know the number of lines (ex 11).  I want to use an array list instead of an array so that Im not forced to predefine the # of indices.

```
import java.io.*;

public class ReadMyFile {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    FileReader reader = new FileReader("data.txt");
    System.out.println("We have made a FileReader");

    char [] data = new char[11];
    reader.read(data);
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      System.out.print(data[i]);
    }
    reader.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you quote that documentation and provide a link?

Comment: 1) What "oracle documentation"? 2) What do you mean by "takes basic arrays"? 3) What does a `FileReader` have to do with arrays or lists or whatever?

Comment: Loop through it and write the contents of each entry. Whats not to understand? You dont need some special class to read lists

Comment: I don't know what you're speaking of, but to convert from a List to an Array, use `type[] = (type[]) collection.toArray(new type[collection.size()]);`

Comment: The only FileReader that I found in the Oracle J2SE set is https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/, and I couldn't find one in the J2EE library.  The java.io.FileReader didn't seem to have anything like what you mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `read()` method instead of `read(some_array)` like that:

```
List<Character> charList = new ArrayList<>()
char c;
while ((c = reader.read()) != -1) {
    charList.add(c);
}
```

`read()` reads one character so you can create a loop and read characters one by one and after reading every character you can add that character to a list. When there are no more characters to read `read()` returns -1 and that terminates a loop.